# How does curl print to terminal while piping

Tags: command-line, curl, redirect

When I `curl` a file, and pipe it to a file or another command, I see output in my terminal. I am not sure how this happens, as the pipe is supposed to take all the output from curl, right?

For example:

```
$ curl http://www.archive.org/stream/Pi_to_100000000_places/pi.txt > /dev/null
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  129M    0  129M    0     0  22.5M      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:-- 24.7M
```

---

### Edit

I use curl like this:

```
curl http://www.archive.org/stream/Pi_to_100000000_places/pi.txt | some_other_command > some_file
```

I do not want to pipe the status to some_other_command, I was just wondering how it was able to display the status. However, showing how to redirect both streams added to the answer, so don't remove that.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/173209/53494.

Comment: You're redirecting `curl`'s output to `/dev/null` for *testing*, right? I'm asking because the answers so far all feature how to redirect its standard output and standard error streams *together*. But if you're using `curl` to download files on standard output, you do *not* want to redirect stdout and stderr to the same place--any output on stderr would corrupt the download! I know you've already accepted an answer, but would you be willing to **[edit]** this with an example of how you're using `curl`? I think that would make this question more valuable to future readers in similar situations.

Comment: @EliahKagan Sure, thanks for the suggestion. I am piping it to `/dev/null` just for demonstration

Comment: Maybe you want to do this? echo `curl -s http://api.ipify.org` | some_command

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two output streams generally available: standard output, and standard error. In practice, when running in a terminal, both send data to the terminal. `>` only redirects standard output, and curl prints the progress data to standard error. To suppress both, use one of:

```bsh
curl ... > /dev/null 2>&1
curl ... &> /dev/null    # bash's combined redirection operator
curl -s ...    # -s, --silent: Silent or quiet mode. Don't show progress meter or error messages.
```

To send both to a pipe:

```bsh
curl ... 2>&1 | ...
curl |& ...    # bash's combined pipe
```

Unless you use the `|&` or `&>` operators, all streams are redirected independently.

Also see:

- [Stack Overflow: confused about stdin, stdout and stderr?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3385201/2072269)

Comment: Seems like this also works with `&>>` to output to a file. As mentioned without putting curl into silent mode then the contents include the progress data, but I actually want that in my case.

Answer (score 3):

When you are using `curl` to open an URL, you'll get two output:

1. The status of the `curl` itself.
2. The contents of that URL.

Curl should use a way to show these two separately otherwise processing of the real output (URL's content) would be hard and I'll end up with unnecessary contents (curl's status).

So it uses `stderr` for its status and `stdout` for the content.

Using `>` you are redirecting the URL's content (stdout) to the `/dev/null`, you should actually use: `2> /dev/null` instead.

Also if you want to pip both of them to the next command:

```
curl url |&  command
```

If you only want the content be piped to next command while not seeing the status:

```
curl 2> /dev/null | command
```